# $_POST['name'] Returns Value with Symbol

Tags: php, jquery

here my `$.post()` call

```
$('.view_search_btn').click(function(){
            var search_key = $('input[name=view_stu_search]').val();
            $.post('../view_student_search.php',{key: 'view_student_search_key',search_keyword: search_key},function(data){
                alert(data);
            });<!-- $.post call close here -->
        });
```

here my PHP code (`view_student_search.php`)

PHP code return following result for

[image]

Actually I passed value 21 to PHP page but it returns 21 with symbol.

Comment: Do debug in your browser to see real payload of post request. In php try to use var_dump instead of echo.

Comment: I guess this is an encoding problem. have you checked if all of your files are using the same character encoding? also make sure your html file is using the right encoding in the content-type meta-tag; eg. for utf-8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check encoding on client and backend.